# zf2 with doctrine2 - how can I find out what's wrong?

Tags: debugging, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I try to learn Doctrine2 now so I created a trivial Entity (actually I got it from tutorial):

```
<?php

namespace Application\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I also created an action to create and persist such product:

```
public function createProductAction() {
    $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $em->getConnection()
       ->getConfiguration()
       ->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());
    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName("Test product");

    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

    echo "Created product with ID ".$product->getId();
}
```

Of course before test I've ran a command to create db scheme (and checked that it's actually created). Simillar code for User runs smoothly but this action reports following:

```
"START TRANSACTION" INSERT INTO Product (name) VALUES (?)

array (size=1)
  1 => null

array (size=1)
  1 => string 'string' (length=6)

"ROLLBACK"
```

What's wrong?? Is there anyway to debug it somehow?? :|

Comment: You'll need a `public function setId($id)`

Comment: No, Id is set automatically by Doctrine. The problem was more trivial: `setName($name)` doesn't set name (I missed `= $name` in first line). :)